# subtle differences in creating new list?

Tags: c#, list

I am to c# and have been putting programs together through modification of existing code in visual studio. I am looking for some guidance to understand the difference between two ways of creating a list. both compile:

```
List <int> myList;

//versus

List <int> myList = new List <int>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not subtle. One creates a list and one does not.

The first one simply declares a reference to a list. You would have to create the list later, before using it.

The second one declares a reference to a list and creates a list and sets the reference to refer to the new list, all at the same time.

Comment: while this is true, I'm guessing that @GIStack could use some more help: the first statement **declares** a variable of type `List<int>`, whereas the second statement declares **and creates** (or instantiates, if you will) a variable of type `List<int>`

Comment: If you use the first one, then at some point later in the program you would likely use this line: myList = new List <int>();   in order to give the variable a value.  But you could also say something like myList = cityList;   where cityList is another variable of type List<int> declared and initialized elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 3):

The first one `List myList;` simply declares the variable, but the value is unassigned.  The second one actually creates a new List object with no entries in it.

You should use the second option in most cases.

Comment: If it's a local variable, it's not `null`, it's unassigned.

Comment: @svick it is too null, you can compare it vs null in an expression and it would return true.

Comment: @ChuckSavage, nope, you can't. If you try to compile something like `List<int> list; bool isNull = list == null;`, you get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

The first line just creates a variable to hold a reference to a list.

The second one initializes the refrence with an empty list.

An attempt to call any method/access property on a reference without initializing it will end up in a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

```
List <int> myList;
```

is the same as writing

```
List <int> myList = null; // aka it is not a list yet
```

Comment: That's not true if `myList` is a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first line doesn't create a `List<int>` object. It only declares a variable named `myList`  that's of the type `List<int>`. If you tried to do anything with that variable as is, the compiler would complain, because it's uninitialized.

The second line declares the variable and initializes it to a value: a new `List<int>` object.